# Adding parameter to every jqGrid ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

When there is a jqGrid on the page I want to extend it to pass an extra parameter in. My best attempt so far:

```
...
    $('[role=grid]').jqGrid('setGridParam', { 'serializeGridData':MyGridOnBeforeRequest });

    function MyGridOnBeforeRequest (postData) {
        var newPostData = $.extend(postData, {
            specialParam: "foo"
        });
        return $.param(newPostData);
    }
...
```

I am doing it this way because it looks like jqGrid ignores any changes you do to jQuery's ajax handling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the code which you posted should work and *at the next grid reloading* the new `serializeGridData` will be used.

It's only a little strange that you use `serializeGridData` in the way in which you as posted. It's enough to use `postData` parameter instead:

```
var postData = $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', "postData");
$.extend(postData: {specialParam: "foo"});
```

Moreover in your original code you use `$.extend(postData, {specialParam: "foo"});` which *modify* the original `postData`. It's not bad, but in general the code

```
function myGridOnBeforeRequest (postData) {
    return $.extend({}, postData, {specialParam: "foo"});
}
```

or even

```
function myGridOnBeforeRequest (postData) {
    return $.extend(true, {}, postData, {specialParam: "foo"});
}
```

will be more clean. The usage of `$.param` is not really needed. If you return an object then jQuery.ajax will make the call of `$.param` automatically for you.

One more very common way will be to define grids directly with the `postData` parameter which looks like

```
postData: {
    specialParam: function () { return "foo"; }
}
```

In the way you can implement more logic in the function, you can use some variables from the outer scote inside of the body of the function or get some values from the controls existing on the page (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for details). In the case you can implement *dynamic* `specialParam` without the usage of `getGridParam`.

The last remark. Already from the color of `myGridOnBeforeRequest` (compare it with the color of `MyGridOnBeforeRequest` from your question) one can see that it will be interpreted in another way. If the name of the function start with the capital letter it means correspond with common used name conversion that you define **constructor** of the new class `MyGridOnBeforeRequest`. You have to use it as `var test = new MyGridOnBeforeRequest();`: using `new`. Just compare with `var now = new Date();`. It is strictly recommended to hold the standard JavaScript name conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If it is going to be some setting that is not going to change much you can add it to the 
`$.jgrid.defaults` by using something like this

```
function getSpecialParam()
{
    return 'foo';
}
$.jgrid.defaults = $.extend($.jgrid.defaults,
    {
        postedData:{
            specialParam:getSpeicalParam
        }
    });
```